# closing mysql database connection in python flask application

Tags: python, flask, cleardb

This Python / Flask / MySQL web application is used to help a business change the message on their advertising signs.

I recently upgraded my heroku mysql database to cleardb. Lately I cannot run the application because it keeps giving me the error message

**MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1226, "User 'b6e526988cfe5a' has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 15)")**

I have put try-finally blocks in each of my functions to ensure the connection is closed every time, yet I still get this error. Where am I going wrong? I tried using conn.close() in the finally block, but then it gives me a "2006" error.

```
from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, redirect, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session
from tempfile import mkdtemp
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

# using login required from helpers from the "Finance" problem set
from helpers import login_required, check_available_chars

# Configure application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Ensure templates are auto-reloaded
app.config["TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD"] = True

# Configure session to use filesystem (instead of signed cookies)
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] = mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
app.secret_key = [CENSORED]
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = True
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] =  [CENSORED]
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] =  [CENSORED]
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] =  [CENSORED]
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] =  [CENSORED]
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
app.config['MYSQL_CHARSET'] = 'utf8mb4'

mysql = MySQL(app)

# Sample function

@app.route("/change", methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def change():
    
    conn = mysql.connection
    cur = conn.cursor()
    
    try:
        cur.execute("SELECT doubleSided, prevMessage1, prevMessage2 from businesses WHERE businessID = %s", (int(session['user_id']),))
        currentMessageData = cur.fetchall()[0]
        doubleSided = True if int(currentMessageData['doubleSided']) == 1 else False
        if doubleSided:
            currentMessages = [currentMessageData['prevMessage1'],currentMessageData['prevMessage2']]
        else:
            currentMessages = [currentMessageData['prevMessage1']]

        cur.close()
        
        return render_template("change.html", doubleSided=doubleSided, currentMessages=currentMessages)
    finally:
        cur.close()
```

Comment: Do you have a connection pool? If yes, what is its size?

Comment: each request will create a new connection. Using singleton connection to avoid it

Comment: @Shadow what pooling method would you use? I've tried two. The first was MySQLConnectionPool, and it seems to connect to the database just fine, but I've found no information on how to commit an insert, update, or delete statement. The second was flask_mysqlpool, which refuses to connect at all because of a "unknown collation - utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci" error. (For the record, I'm using a Punch MySQL database as a heroku addon)

Comment: @TanThien can you recommend how I can make a singleton connection in Flask, using MySQL?